# Make vars constant for use in case statements in Clojure

Tags: clojure

In Clojure, is there a way to make a var constant such that it can be used in `case` statements?

e.g.

```
(def a 1)
(def b 2)

(let [x 1]
  (case x
    a :1
    b :2
    :none))
=> :none
```

I understand I can use something like `cond` or `condp` to get around this, but it would be nice if I could define something that does not require further evaluation so I could use `case`.

Comment: using a hash-map requires no further evaluation, and compiles to something pretty close to what a case would compile to

Comment: @noisesmith A hash-map needs to be instantiated and looked up. Both requires evaluation. Implementation wise hash-map lookup is not even close to what case compiles to.

Comment: The instantiation can happen at compile time, if we are emulating a case statement. My understanding was that a case statement compiled to a hash lookup in bytecode but don't have the proof handy.

Comment: @LeonGrapenthin [this function](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.7.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L6327) leads me to believe case does in fact compile to a hash lookup.

Comment: @noisesmith Admittedly there is more hashing going on than I originally thought. Still not convinced on the "pretty close" part, especially in this case where the constants are all numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Related and answer stolen from it:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16777814/is-it-possible-to-use-clojures-case-form-with-a-java-enum)

As the docstring tells you: No you cannot do this. You can use [Chas Emericks macro](http://cemerick.com/2010/08/03/enhancing-clojures-case-to-evaluate-dispatch-values/) and do this however:

```
(defmacro case+
  "Same as case, but evaluates dispatch values, needed for referring to
   class and def'ed constants as well as java.util.Enum instances."
  [value & clauses]
  (let [clauses (partition 2 2 nil clauses)
        default (when (-> clauses last count (== 1))
                  (last clauses))
        clauses (if default (drop-last clauses) clauses)
        eval-dispatch (fn [d]
                        (if (list? d)
                          (map eval d)
                          (eval d)))]
    `(case ~value
       ~@(concat (->> clauses
                   (map #(-> % first eval-dispatch (list (second %))))
                   (mapcat identity))
           default))))
```

Thus:

```
(def ^:const a 1)
(def ^:const b 2)
(let [x 1]
  (case+ x
    a :1
    b :2
    :none))
=> :1
```

An alternative (which is nice since it's more powerful) is to use `core.match`'s functionality. Though you can only match against *local* bindings:

```
(let [x 2
      a a
      b b]
  (match x
    a :1
    b :2
    :none))
 => :2
```

Comment: I thought ^:const would replace the vars with their respective literals at compilation time. Is there a way to enforce that?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `clojure.core/condp` for the job:

```
(def a 1)
(def b 2)
(let [x 1]
  (condp = x
    a :1
    b :2
    :none))
#=> :1
```